# Validations on django modelforms

Tags: python, django, django-1.7

I am following [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute) to add a custom validation on my modelform and it is working...mostly.

My code:

```
from django import forms
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

from datetimewidget.widgets import DateWidget

from .models import User

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        # Set this form to use the User model.
        model = User

        # Constrain the UserForm to just these fields.
        fields = ("birthdate")
        widgets = {
            'birthdate': DateWidget(attrs={'id':"id_birthdate"}, bootstrap_version=3)
        }

    def clean_birthdate(self):
        birthdate = self.cleaned_data["birthdate"]
        min_time = datetime.strptime('1920-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d').date()
        delta = birthdate - min_time
        if  delta <= timedelta(days=0):
            raise forms.ValidationError(_("We don't accept people born before 1920"))
        return birthdate
```

It raises the error like intended until 1900-01-01, but once i enter to 1899 it doesn't.
I am not sure what may be causing it. I am using [DateTimeWidget](https://github.com/asaglimbeni/django-datetime-widget).

The error i am getting is:

```
year=1899 is before 1900; the datetime strftime() methods require year >= 1900
```

I checked the result of the comparison and it is working as intended (False for years below 1920).

In short model is being updated and error is not being raised when it should.

Answer (score 1):

This is a limitation of python's built-in strftime function. It does not support dates prior to 1900. Try this instead

```
if birthdate.year < 1920:
    raise forms.ValidationError(_("We don't accept people born before 1920"))
```

Comment: Tried it. Still ignores the validation.
The issue is not the evaluation of a function (at least at that point). The value for both your expression and mine are False when the year is below 1920, but the raise is not getting reached as it should

Comment: Yeah, strftime has the >=1900 limitation, and it is running from the widget.  You will need to either monkeypatch the widget to use `isoformat()`, or not use the widget, and do some check like daniel tiesling has mentioned.